# Querying from two tables with EntityManager

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have two entities - 'Product' and 'Opinion'.

**Product**

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(length = 100)
  @NotEmpty
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "opinion", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  Set<Opinion> opinions = new HashSet<>();
```

**Opinion**

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Min(0)
  @Max(10)
  private Integer rating;

  @Length(max=200)
  private String description;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Product product;
```

I would like to implement the following method:
`List<Product> findProductsWithAverageRatingLowerThan(Integer rating)`.
The implementation of this method should find all products, that have a rating lower than passed as an argument. If product has no opinion, than its rating should be zero.

Here's my approach:

```
public List<Product> findProductWithAverageRatingLowerThan(Integer rating) {
  return entityManager
    .createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.opinions < " +
      "(SELECT o.product, AVG(o.rating) AS av FROM Opinion o WHERE av < :rating GROUP BY o.product)", Product.class)
    .setParameter("rating", rating)
    .getResultList();
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatible [java.util.Set(com.myexample.Product.opinions) : com.myexample.Product]
```

Comment: Your product may have a variety of opinions that you want to compare to a one number.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your query. I tried a few things and I hope I got it correct on my side.

Try this one:

```sql
select Product.*
from Product
         join (select Opinion.product_id, avg(Opinion.rating) as avg
               from Opinion
               group by Opinion.product_id) as queryAvg on Product.id = queryAvg.product_id
where queryAvg.avg < :rating;
```

Or without subquery this should work too:

```sql
select Product.*
from Product
join Opinion on Product.id = Opinion .product_id
group by Product.id
having avg(Opinion.rating) < :rating;
```